# How to make this figure using pgfplots in Latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, floats, plot

I try to find a example to make a similar figure equal this example but not found.
[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are asking to draw something of that sort with `pgfplots`. `pgfplots` is a good choice because it can color the grid as a function of the 3d coordinates. This is illustrated here

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare
function={rrr(\x,\y,\z)=sqrt(1+0.1*(\x*\x+\y*\y+\z*\z));}]
\begin{axis}[axis equal,
        width=10cm,
        height=10cm,
        hide axis,
        view={15}{8},
        scale uniformly strategy=units only,
        point meta={symbolic={0.1-0.08*y, % R 
            1-sqrt(x*x+y*y+z*z)/sqrt(4), % G 
            sqrt(x*x+y*y+z*z)/sqrt(4)%B
            } },                   
        domain = -1:1,
        samples y=1,enlargelimits=0.2,
        axis background/.style={fill=black}]
% this example burns colors if opacity 
% is active in the document.
 \fill[white] (0,0,0) circle[radius=0.1cm];
 \foreach \X in {-1,-1/3,1/3,1}
  {\foreach \Y in {-1,-1/3,1/3,1}
    {\edef\temp{\noexpand\addplot3 [thick,patch, patch type=bilinear,
        mesh/color input=explicit mathparse] 
        ({x*rrr(x,\X,\Y)}, {\X*rrr(x,\X,\Y)}, {\Y*rrr(x,\X,\Y)});
        \noexpand\addplot3 [thick,patch, patch type=bilinear,
        mesh/color input=explicit mathparse] ( {\X*rrr(x,\X,\Y)},{x*rrr(x,\X,\Y)},{\Y*rrr(x,\X,\Y)});
        \noexpand\addplot3 [thick,patch, patch type=bilinear,
        mesh/color input=explicit mathparse] ( {\X*rrr(x,\X,\Y)},{\Y*rrr(x,\X,\Y)},{x*rrr(x,\X,\Y)});
        \noexpand\addplot3 [only marks,mark=ball,scatter,scatter src=1,
        samples at={-1,-0.333,0.333,1},
         mark options={ball color=white}] ( {\X*rrr(x,\X,\Y)},{x*rrr(x,\X,\Y)},{\Y*rrr(x,\X,\Y)});      
        }
    \temp}} 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, `pgfplots` is not a good choice to draw things in perspective. For this the `perspective` library is a much better choice. So if you want to have the view as in your screen shot, I'd encourage you to ask a *separate* question on how to draw this using the `perspective` library.

Nonetheless, you may fake the perspective, and make the distant layers "fade away". This is achieved by making the (inverse) "metrics" `rrr` depend on `y`. (If you plan to play with `rrr`: note that the RGB functions need to get fed with values between `0` and `1`.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare
function={rrr(\x,\y,\z)=sqrt(1+0.1*(\x*\x+\y*\y+\z*\z))/(1+0.1*\y);}]
\begin{axis}[axis equal,
        width=10cm,
        height=10cm,
        hide axis,
        clip mode=individual,
        view={8}{8},
        scale uniformly strategy=units only,
        point meta={symbolic={0.1-0.055*y, % R 
            1-sqrt(x*x+y*y+z*z)/sqrt(5), % G 
            sqrt(x*x+y*y+z*z)/sqrt(5)%B
            } },                   
        domain = -1:1,
        samples y=1,enlargelimits=0.2,
        axis background/.style={fill=black}]
% this example burns colors if opacity 
% is active in the document.
%\clip (current axis.south west) rectangle (current axis.north west);
 \foreach \Y in {1,0.333,-0.333,-1}
 {\foreach \X in {-1,-0.333,0.333,1}
    {\edef\temp{\noexpand\addplot3 [thick,patch, patch type=bilinear,
        mesh/color input=explicit mathparse] 
        ({x*rrr(x,\Y,\X)},{\Y*rrr(x,\Y,\X)},{\X*rrr(x,\Y,\X)});
        \noexpand\addplot3 [thick,patch, patch type=bilinear,
        mesh/color input=explicit mathparse] ( {\X*rrr(x,\Y,\X)},{\Y*rrr(x,\Y,\X)},{x*rrr(x,\Y,\X)});
        }
     \temp}
  \foreach \X in {-1,-0.333,0.333,1}
    {\edef\temp{%
        \noexpand\addplot3 [mark layer=like plot,only marks,mark=ball,scatter,scatter src=1,
        samples at={-1,-0.333,0.333,1},mark options={ball color=white}] 
         ({\X*rrr(\X,\Y,x)},{\Y*rrr(\X,\Y,x)},{x*rrr(\X,\Y,x)});
        \ifdim\Y pt>-1pt       
        \noexpand\addplot3 [thick,patch, patch type=bilinear,
         mesh/color input=explicit mathparse,domain=\Y-0.06:\Y-0.6667] 
         ({\X*rrr(\X,x,1)},
         {x*rrr(\X,x,1)},{1*rrr(\X,x,1)});
        \noexpand\addplot3 [thick,patch, patch type=bilinear,
         mesh/color input=explicit mathparse,domain=\Y-0.06:\Y-0.6667] 
         ({\X*rrr(\X,x,0.333)},
         {x*rrr(\X,x,0.333)},{0.333*rrr(\X,x,0.333)});
        \noexpand\addplot3 [thick,patch, patch type=bilinear,
         mesh/color input=explicit mathparse,domain=\Y-0.06:\Y-0.6667] 
         ({\X*rrr(\X,x,-0.333)},
         {x*rrr(\X,x,-0.333)},{-0.333*rrr(\X,x,-0.333)});
        \noexpand\addplot3 [thick,patch, patch type=bilinear,
         mesh/color input=explicit mathparse,domain=\Y-0.06:\Y-0.6667] 
         ({\X*rrr(\X,x,-1)},
         {x*rrr(\X,x,-1)},{-1*rrr(\X,x,-1)});
        \noexpand\path[fill=black,fill opacity=0.1] (-1.2,\Y+0.667,-1.2) -- 
        (1.2,\Y+0.667,-1.2) -- (1.2,\Y+0.667,1.2) -- (-1.2,\Y+0.667,1.2) 
        -- cycle;
        \fi
        }
    \temp}}
 \fill[white] (0,0,0) circle[radius=0.1cm];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with a blurry light source in the center.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare
function={rrr(\x,\y,\z)=sqrt(1+0.1*(\x*\x+\y*\y+\z*\z))/(1+0.1*\y);}]
\begin{axis}[axis equal,
        width=10cm,
        height=10cm,
        hide axis,
        clip mode=individual,
        view={8}{8},
        scale uniformly strategy=units only,
        point meta={symbolic={0.1-0.055*y, % R 
            1-sqrt(x*x+y*y+z*z)/sqrt(5), % G 
            sqrt(x*x+y*y+z*z)/sqrt(5)%B
            } },                   
        domain = -1:1,
        samples y=1,enlargelimits=0.2,
        axis background/.style={fill=black}]
% this example burns colors if opacity 
% is active in the document.
%\clip (current axis.south west) rectangle (current axis.north west);
 \foreach \Y in {1,0.333,-0.333,-1}
 {\foreach \X in {-1,-0.333,0.333,1}
    {\edef\temp{\noexpand\addplot3 [thick,patch, patch type=bilinear,
        mesh/color input=explicit mathparse] 
        ({x*rrr(x,\Y,\X)},{\Y*rrr(x,\Y,\X)},{\X*rrr(x,\Y,\X)});
        \noexpand\addplot3 [thick,patch, patch type=bilinear,
        mesh/color input=explicit mathparse] ( {\X*rrr(x,\Y,\X)},{\Y*rrr(x,\Y,\X)},{x*rrr(x,\Y,\X)});
        }
     \temp}
  \foreach \X in {-1,-0.333,0.333,1}
    {\edef\temp{%
        \noexpand\addplot3 [mark layer=like plot,only marks,mark=ball,scatter,scatter src=1,
        samples at={-1,-0.333,0.333,1},mark options={ball color=white}] 
         ({\X*rrr(\X,\Y,x)},{\Y*rrr(\X,\Y,x)},{x*rrr(\X,\Y,x)});
        \ifdim\Y pt>-1pt       
        \noexpand\addplot3 [thick,patch, patch type=bilinear,
         mesh/color input=explicit mathparse,domain=\Y-0.06:\Y-0.6667] 
         ({\X*rrr(\X,x,1)},
         {x*rrr(\X,x,1)},{1*rrr(\X,x,1)});
        \noexpand\addplot3 [thick,patch, patch type=bilinear,
         mesh/color input=explicit mathparse,domain=\Y-0.06:\Y-0.6667] 
         ({\X*rrr(\X,x,0.333)},
         {x*rrr(\X,x,0.333)},{0.333*rrr(\X,x,0.333)});
        \noexpand\addplot3 [thick,patch, patch type=bilinear,
         mesh/color input=explicit mathparse,domain=\Y-0.06:\Y-0.6667] 
         ({\X*rrr(\X,x,-0.333)},
         {x*rrr(\X,x,-0.333)},{-0.333*rrr(\X,x,-0.333)});
        \noexpand\addplot3 [thick,patch, patch type=bilinear,
         mesh/color input=explicit mathparse,domain=\Y-0.06:\Y-0.6667] 
         ({\X*rrr(\X,x,-1)},
         {x*rrr(\X,x,-1)},{-1*rrr(\X,x,-1)});
        \noexpand\path[fill=black,fill opacity=0.1] (-1.2,\Y+0.667,-1.2) -- 
        (1.2,\Y+0.667,-1.2) -- (1.2,\Y+0.667,1.2) -- (-1.2,\Y+0.667,1.2) 
        -- cycle;
        \fi
        }
    \temp}}
 \foreach \X in {0.9,0.8,...,0}
  {\edef\temp{\noexpand\fill[white,opacity=1-\X,even odd rule] 
    (0,0,0) circle[radius=0.1cm+\X*0.04cm+0.004cm]
circle[radius=0.1cm+\X*0.04cm];}
   \temp}
 \fill[white] (0,0,0) circle[radius=0.1cm];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The central dot needs to be made more convincingly spherical... (It's a wonderful answer.)

Comment: @Anush I added a more blurry source. The results are somewhat viewer-dependent.

Comment: Almost seems a raytrancing image.  It's a shame that this  can't be exported to povray or blender.

Comment: @Fran One can certainly improve it by e.g. rotating the little spheres (with `transform canvas`) but as you imply there are tools that are probably more suited for this task.